# Removing leading square brackets from JSON using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper, sap-cpi

I need a way to remove leading square brackets from a JSON file. I'm doing it in SAP cloud platform integration (CPI). Currently I was thinking of using groovy but can't seem to find a way to do it. Here's the JSON example:

```
[{
        "salesOrderNumber": "1234567",
        "orderStatus": "Complete",
        "customerPONumber": "7654321",
        "soldToID": "ABC",
        "soldToName": "CBA"

    }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

The code I used was for getting just one element, but I need to get multiple in case there are many.

```
def Message processData(Message message) {

    def body = message.getBody(String.class);
    def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper();
    def jsonObject = jsonParser.parseText(body);

    def json = JsonOutput.toJson(jsonObject[0]);

    println(json);

    message.setBody(json);
    
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of objects in json. Remove square brackets means get rid of the list and keep only one element of this list.

> Btw, what if there are several or zero elements in the list?

So, your algorithm

- parse json
- get first element `list[0]`
- serialize result back into json

As a code reference look at this documentation: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html

Comment: Yeah if theres multiple elements it doesn't work. Thinking of a way for it to work with multiple elements.

Comment: What do you need to get when multiple objects in array?

Comment: The same basically as before. Remove square brackets, But now to make sure that all elements are in the output. I tried to make a loop but that didn't work.